# How can I use alias name in where clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

how can i use alias name in where clause in mysql

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE roles.rol_active
        WHEN '1' THEN 'yes'
        WHEN '0' THEN 'no'
    END AS roles_active
FROM
    roles
WHERE
    rol_is_deleted = 
 AND (rol_name LIKE '%ac%' 
  OR rol_display_name LIKE '%ac%'
  OR rol_description LIKE '%ac%'
  OR rol_active LIKE '%ac%'
  OR rol_updated_by LIKE '%ac%'
  OR rol_updated_at LIKE '%ac%')
ORDER BY rol_name asc
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap a part of your current query up in a derived table:

```
select * from
(
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE roles.rol_active
        WHEN '1' THEN 'yes'
        WHEN '0' THEN 'no'
    END AS roles_active
FROM
    roles
) as dt
WHERE
    rol_is_deleted = 
 AND (rol_name LIKE '%ac%' 
  OR rol_display_name LIKE '%ac%'
  OR rol_description LIKE '%ac%'
  OR rol_active LIKE '%ac%'
  OR rol_updated_by LIKE '%ac%'
  OR rol_updated_at LIKE '%ac%')
ORDER BY rol_name asc
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

You can even have two separate `WHERE` clauses. One for column conditions in the sub-query, and another one for column alias conditions in the outer query. I.e. something like:

```
...
WHERE column-conditions
) as dt
WHERE column-alias-conditions
...
```

Comment: in case of joing what we can do

Comment: Same strategy as above, i.e. put the join as a derived table, move column alias conditions to the outer WHERE clause.

Answer (score 3):

You actually can't, because `select` clause is evaluated after the `where` clause (there are no aliases at that point). However, you can use a `having` clause instead or use a temporary table.

Comment: after where clause i used having clause also but .........in that case only having clause condition is checked........what can i do in this

Comment: can u plz elaborate on that ....because i can't filter more than one records while using having clause

Comment: @mahes: change `where` to `having`.